# ASP.NET page getting Timeout expired requiring the application pool being recycled every hour

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timeout, sqlconnection, application-pool

My new application page is getting a timeout error every hour or so after getting some traffic on the page, and by traffic I mean users submitting 5-10 applications. How do I find the cause of the connections getting tied up?

This has been an issue in the past so whenever I use a sql data reader object I make sure to implement the "Using" statement. I've also made sure that the thread isn't aborted before the data reader is disposed of. I doubt that my use of data readers is the issue, so maybe it's my non-query code that's causing the issue, but I can't see why.

I also use a few sqldatasource objects for my dropdownlist controls, and as far as I know it wouldn't be the source of my issue.

See code example for how I use my sql objects.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Using drApp As SqlDataReader = LookupAppByID()
            'some code
        drApp.Close()
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function LookupAppByID() As SqlDataReader
    Dim Command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

    Command.Connection = GetDBConnection()
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Command.CommandText = "select statement"

    Return Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
End Function

Public Function UpdateAppStatus() As Integer
    UpdateAppStatus = 0
    Using Command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("update statement", GetDBConnection())
        UpdateAppStatus = Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Command.Connection.Close()
        Command.Connection.Dispose()
        Command.Dispose()
    End Using
End Function

Public Function GetDBConnection() As SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "connection string"
    connection.Open()
    Return connection
End Function
```

Obviously I expect it to chug along without a hitch but when users start hitting the page it gets this error: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Is there a problem with my code?
How can I narrow down what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the database objects local so I can ensure that they are closed and disposed. Create and dispose within one method. I created a class so you can easily pass all its properties in a single variable.

```
'User Interface Code
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim id As Integer 'No sure where the value comes from
    Using dtApp As DataTable = DataAccess.LookupAppByID(id)
        'some code
    End Using
End Sub

Protected Sub Update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Update.Click
    Dim Applic As New ApplicationData()
    Applic.ApplicantsName = txtName.Text
    Applic.ID = CInt(txtID.Tex)
    Applic.ApplicationStatus = "Approved"
    Dim retVal = DataAccess.UpdateAppStatus(Applic)
    If retVal = 1 Then
        'Alert user of success
    Else
        'Alert user of failure
    End If
End Sub

Public Class ApplicationData
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property AppDate As Date
    Public Property ApplicantsName As String
    Public Property ApplicationStatus As String
End Class

Public Class DataAccess
    Private Shared ConString As String = "Your connection string"
    Public Shared Function LookupAppByID(AppID As Integer) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConString)
            Using Command As New SqlCommand("select * From YourTable Where ID = @ID", cn)
                Command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = AppID
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(Command.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function

    Public Shared Function UpdateAppStatus(App As ApplicationData) As Integer
        Dim AppStatus = 0
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConString)
            Using Command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Update YourTable Set Status = @Status Where ID = @ID;", cn)
                Command.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = App.ApplicationStatus
                Command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = App.ID
                cn.Open()
                AppStatus = Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
        Return AppStatus
    End Function
End Class
```